# I do not have the **App_Start** folder in a Web Api project when the project is created using the `dotnet new webapi` command

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-code, project

I do not have the **App_Start** folder in a Web Api project when the project is created using the `dotnet new webapi` command. Why?

I am using the VS Code and follow the tutorial over [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/configure-web-api). In the tutorial the Visual Studio is used and I thought that I could accomplish everything that can be accomplished in Visual Studio in VS Code as well. It seems that is not the case.

I see the following project structure, which is definitely different from the one created in Visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dotnet` CLI is for .NET Core.

The tutorial you're following is for .NET Framework.

There's nothing wrong here, and you can use VS Code for .NET framework projects.

However, the `dotnet` CLI has .NET Core templates. It's strongly recommended to start new development in .NET Core.

Basically, find an up-to-date tutorial.

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much for the answer. So, the tutorial I linked is about the .NET Framework WebApi and the project I am creating in a VS Code is a .NET Core WebApi. Is it correct?